# All div's are showing when hover a img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".hardware").hover( function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
        $(".info").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

And my html:

```
<section>
    <div class="hardware banner1 top">
        <img src="files/images/sakesalverda.png" alt="" class="action"/>
        <div class="info">sakesalverda.nl</div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="hardware banner2">
        <img src="files/images/ptsd-monitor.png" alt="" class="action"/>
        <div class="info">ptsd-monitor.com</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But when you hover `.hardware.banner1` it will show both divs. I only wan't it to show the div which is in the `banner` and not the one which is in the `banner2`.

Comment: The event type will be the same for each `.hardware`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
$(this).find('.info').fadeIn(500);
```

Since you want to `fadeIn` the `.info` inside `.hardware` and not all of them.